# Azure Deployment Error: cannot find ClientPerfCountersInstaller.exe

Tags: deployment, azure

I recently tried setting up the Preview Cache for Azure on an existing site and deployment, which I had to abort due to errors.  However since then I now get the following error when I try and deploy to Azure...

Cannot find file named `approot\bin\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching\ClientPerfCountersInstaller.exe`

This file does exist on disk, presuming approot is the base folder for my ASP project.

Any ideas and help greatly appreciated, am banging my head against the wall currently!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found the solution.  The ServiceDefinition.csdef file had a new startup task that had been created somehow during the cache setup process.  Removing this superfluous task resolved the issue and I cannot see any down side or negative impact.

Commented out line is shown below...

```
<Startup priority="-2">
  <!--<Task commandLine="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching\ClientPerfCountersInstaller.exe install" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple" />-->
</Startup>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this defeat the purpose of activating the client cache on the server?

Comment: Interesting comment, and I did think about it beforehand, but it does not seem to be required to enable caching.  I suspect however it may impact the ability to gather performance stats on the cache in the production environment.  That however was not important to me at this point in time.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the file was created by the Azure SDK tools, but TFVC did not check-in the .exe.

After explicitly adding the missing .exe the build runs successfully.

Comment: I added the .EXE explicitely on both the package folder and the folder that gets added to the main project upon installing the package. I also checked that the files are marked with "Copy always" on build. But keep getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue with absence of `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching\ClientPerfCountersInstaller.exe` by just removing the **`Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching` package** from my solution using **"Manage Nuget Packages for Solution..."**. It was not referenced but still was mentioned in `packages.config`... Especially after information that this way of caching support is discontinued and going to be eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue with absence of `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching\ClientPerfCountersInstaller.exe` by just removing the **`Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching` package** from my solution using **"Manage Nuget Packages for Solution..."**. It was not referenced but still was mentioned in `packages.config`... Especially after information that this way of caching support is discontinued and going to be eliminated.

Duplicate of my answer in other question [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964689/azure-deployment-error-cannot-find-clientperfcountersinstaller-exe/41744670#41744670)
For those who just quickly overviews the answers to find the most appropriate way of solving their exact issue after searching by just error message.