# TFS Deployment to Azure Error: cannot find ClientPerfCountersInstaller.exe

Tags: azure, tfs, tfsbuild

I configured our implementation to use the Azure Caching provider to maintain session state between all cloud instances like described here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg185668.aspx

This created a new startup task on my csdef file that always fails with this error:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.0\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets (987): CloudServices64 : Cannot find file named 'approot\bin\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching\ClientPerfCountersInstaller.exe' for startup task Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching\ClientPerfCountersInstaller.exe install of role MyRole.Web.`

The .exe in the nuget package and in the main folder is included in the source control that TFS uses for the deployment.

I found this previous question that addresses this same issue:
[Azure Deployment Error: cannot find ClientPerfCountersInstaller.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14964689/azure-deployment-error-cannot-find-clientperfcountersinstaller-exe)

But the accepted answer states to just delete the startup task that installs the .exe needed for the caching to take place.

Comment: Instead of using Nuget, you could reference the exe & dlls from the C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\.NET SDK\v2.0\ref\Caching directory.  You'll need to point the startup task at the proper location for the exe.  It looks like it is expecting the exe to be set as content in a folder by the name of Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching off the main project directory (at compile time it will copy the content into the bin directory).

Comment: That's the weird thing, the folder and the file are both there :s

Comment: What is the path in your startup task to the exe?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make sure the .exe is marked as `CopyAlways` so that it is copied to your `\bin` directory.

To do so, right click on the .exe in Visual Studio and select properties. Make sure it looks like this:

[image: Copy Always Property setup]

Comment: Similar issue here: A class library referenced by my worker role project referenced Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching V2.2.0.0 but didn´t have the folder as mentioned in this answer.
SOLUTION: Removed and added again the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching.DLL with NuGet Packet Manager and it created the folder for me.

Comment: I had the same issue, but the build action also had to be "None" and it was set to "Content". Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with a dedicate cache worker role, but in my case the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching folder never showed up in VisualStudio. In the end, I had to open the .csproj file for the worker role project and this:

```
<None Include="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching\ClientPerfCountersInstaller.exe.config">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
<None Include="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching\ClientPerfCountersInstaller.exe">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
<None Include="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching\PerformanceCounters.xml">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
```

I put that within the same `<ItemGroup>` tag as the app.config file, and now it's deploying as it should.

Comment: "it seemed" or fixed things?